# PageViewer - Android - Advanced

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to make a viewpager in android. 
I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. + A proper onDestroy function.
My codes works. But.......

It is really slow and it can't deal with pictures more than 150kb!

I also tried enabling hardware acceleration in manifist file but it didn't helped that much.

I need to make a faster implementation of viewpager. 
I need to make the viewpager lighter.

Do you have any suggestions for me or at least a code that has worked fine for you?

I am using android 4.2. Api 17. Android.support.v4 viewpager.

Comment: Your problem is likely not in a "slow" viewpager but in the bitmap management, which is a science in itself and cannot be answered just like that. You can start reading something like: [Bitmap Memory Management](http://ruchitsharma.blogspot.ca/2013/04/android-bitmap-memory-management.html?m=1), take a look at great libraries [1](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [2](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: the fact that your adapter works doesnt mean it's done right. First make sure there are no issues there. Pls paste some of your code

Comment: Alright I will try to read those documents and rewrite the code.